# Plone 5 customisation of home page

Tags: plone

How can you change the large 'Welcome' banner across top of home page.

Also, how can you remove / hide the manage portlets link that is at bottom of home page

Thanks dave

Answer (score 2):

Welcome "hero" banner was implemented using a browser view from Plone 5.0 to Plone 5.0.2 and to change its content you had two alternatives:

- Register through ZCML a new browser view with the same name and your theme's browser layer
- Create a copy of the hero.pt template renamed to Products.CMFPlone.browser.templates.hero.pt in your theme `overrides/` folder. See: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.themingplugins#zope-page-template-overrides

However this was considered difficult and will change in Plone 5.03+. In the new way you just need to create a DIV (or any element) with a class "hero" using TinyMCE and all its content will be placed inside the DIV#hero element from Plone's default theme. This can be done from inside any portlet's RichText field too. And if you want different content for `#hero` in different pages just edit that page or add a portlet there and you're good to go.

See:

- https://community.plone.org/t/how-remove-welcome-learn-about-plone-from-front-page-of-fresh-plone-5-install/1042/34
- https://github.com/plone/plonetheme.barceloneta/pull/83/files
- https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/pull/1374/files